# HTMLAgilityPack: Need to extract colspan-value and others

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to read from a schedule in the internet.

This is a part of the html-code:

```
<TR>
    <TD rowspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD align="center" nowrap=1><font size="3" face="Arial"><B>Monday</B></font> 
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD colspan=2 rowspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD colspan=6 rowspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD width="33%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial"><B>Meeting</B></font></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD width="33%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial"><B>London</B></font></TD>
                <TD width="33%" nowrap=1><font size="2" face="Arial">Smith</font></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD colspan=4 rowspan=12 align="center" nowrap="1">
```

I managed to install HTMLAgilityPack and implemented this code by now. Descendants and skip seem to be ok so far:

```
List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@border='3']")
                    .Descendants("tr") 
                    .Skip(1)  
                    .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() >= 4)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

The result of table is something like this:

- [0] = "Monday"
- [1] = ""
- [2] = "Meeting\r\n \r\n\r\nLondon\r\n\r\n\r\nSmith"
- [3] = ""
- [4] = ... another meeting ...

The colspan value indicates the duration. So my questions is:

How can I make the value of colspan part of my result? I need to know, that the London-meeting begins after 2 time units and lasts for six units.

- [0] = "Monday"
- [1] = ""  // Duration of break is 2
- [2] = "Meeting\r\n \r\n\r\nLondon\r\n \r\n\r\nSmith"  // Duration is 6

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capturing this in an anonymous type is probably easiest:

```
 var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@border='3']")
                .Descendants("tr") 
                .Skip(1)  
                .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() >= 4)
                .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
                    .Select(td => new { Text = td.InnerText.Trim(), Duration = td.Attributes["Colspan"] != null ? td.Attributes["Colspan"].Value: "1").ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Or create an instance of a Tuple:

```
 List<List<Tuple<string, string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@border='3']")
                .Descendants("tr") 
                .Skip(1)  
                .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() >= 4)
                .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
                    .Select(td => new Tuple<string,string>(td.InnerText.Trim(),  td.Attributes["Colspan"] != null ? td.Attributes["Colspan"].Value: "1").ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I believe you want a `:` instead of `,` prior to the `"1"` for your conditional operator.

Comment: @Harrison you're absolutely right. SO should add Intellisense to their editor ;).

Comment: Oops. Did not see comment. Now it works. Great stuff! Thank you!